# What does allocate CPU to process mean in OS?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

I am taking an Operating System module. For our assignment that is related to CPU Scheduling Algorithm using C programming language, one of the instructions stated *"Allocate CPU to process"*. I have searched the internet but to no avail. I still don't really understand what it exactly means. I have no idea how to implement this particular sentence into a C code. I would appreciate a specific and simple example just for my understanding. Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you understand a process to be? What do you understand a CPU to do? What do you understand "scheduling" to mean?

Comment: Study "Round-robin" and "time slices". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling